# Java FX TitledPane .title CSS Selector

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

In my JavaFX application Im using a `TitledPane` and overriding the `Graphic` element to add some special content for my `TitledPane` header. Kinda works like I would expect. Now Im trying to add some css styling to the header. In the JavaFX CSS reference documentation there is the following definition for a `TitledPane` structure:

```
Substructure

title — HBox
text — Label/li>
arrow-button — StackPane/li>
arrow — StackPane
content — StackPane/li>
```

Therefore I can access styling for the title hbox:

```
.my-titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

This works too. Now my problem. Im trying to add a specific padding for the title element depending on some code. My current solution looks like that:

```
[...]
myTitledPane.getStyleClass().set(0, myTitledPane.getStyleClass.get(0) + getSomeCSSStylingClass());
[...]
```

In the CSS I defined styles for all different possibilites which are returned by `getSomeCSSStylingClass()`.

```
.my-titled-pane-sample-one > .title {
    -fx-padding: 10;
}

.my-titled-pane-sample-two > .title {
    -fx-padding: 10;
}
```

But this solution seems horrible. Is there any possibility to do it easier and better? Is there some way to get the `.title` element and add a styling class to it?

Im using Java Version: Java8_31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookup to retrieve the element, and then set an inline style:

```
int padding = ... ;
myTitledPane.lookup(".title").setStyle("-fx-padding: "+padding+"px;");
```

Note that lookups will only work once the first CSS pass has been made (typically this means the titled pane must be shown on the screen); also inline styles are not usually the best approach. However, if the padding is programmatically determined, this is probably the way you want to do this.

If you do want to do this by manipulating style classes, remember that nodes can have multiple styles. So I would probably do something like

```
.my-titled-pane > .title {
    /* common styles for title, eg */
    -fx-background-color: red ;
}
.style-one > .title {
    -fx-padding: 10px ;
}
.style-two > .title {
    -fx-padding: 12px ;
}
/* etc */
```

And then in Java

```
myTitledPane.getStyleClass().add(getSomeCSSStyleClass());
```

Depending on when this code is invoked, you may need to remove style classes to avoid duplicates, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I kinda think the CSS way with adding multiple style classe is the better way. Just tried it and it works great. Accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this inspector for javaFx app: https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view , with this can inspect app search the node and get the CSS rule of a any of this.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better to add a css file under main ressources folder .
then in your css file for example (Style.css) :

```
.title {-fx-padding: px;}
```

then in your java file just add :

```
scene.getStylesheets.add("/css/Style.css")
```